# Can I reliably query the Firebase intraday tables in BigQuery and get 100% of the event data?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I have two Firebase projects (one iOS and one Android) feeding into Bigquery. I need to combine, flatten, and aggregate some specific data from both projects into one combined table so that I can report off of it without querying all bazillion rows across all daily tables.

In order to populate this aggregate table, I currently have two python scripts querying the iOS and Android intraday tables every 5 minutes. The script gets the max timestamp from the aggregate table, then queries the intraday table to get any records with a greater timestamp (I track the max timestamp separately for iOS and Android because they frequently differ).

I am querying the intraday table with this (abbreviated) wildcard syntax:

```
SELECT yadda, yadda, timestamp_micros, 'ios' as platform
FROM `myproject.iOSapp.app_events_intraday*`
WHERE timestamp_micros > (Select max(timestamp_micros) 
                          from myAggregateTable WHERE platform = 'ios' )
```

Is there any danger that when the intraday table flips over to the new day, I will miss any records when my script runs at 23:57 and then again at 00:02?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I thought I would post the results of my testing this for a few months. Here are the basic mechanics as I see them:

1. New `DAY1` intraday table is created at midnight GMT (`xyz.app_events_intraday_20180101`)
2. New `DAY2` intraday table is created 24 hours later (`xyz.app_events_intraday_20180102`), but `DAY1` intraday table sticks around for a few hours
3. Eventually, `DAY1` table is "renamed" to `xyz.app_events_20180101` and you are left with a single (current) intraday table

My tests have shown that additional data *is* added to the `app_events_*` tables, even after step 3 has taken place, so it is **NOT** safe to assume that the data is stable/static once the name has changed. I have new data appear up to 2 or 3 days later.

Comment: Thank for this confirmation !
We are experiencing the same behavior of data still added to renamed tables, up to 3 days after, and we were looking for a confirmation.

Comment: Maybe "event_server_timestamp_offset" field (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62671147) will help.

Comment: Are you sure it’s GMT and not UTC ?

Comment: I'm old so I call it GMT. UTC is probably the better term for it.