# How to extract server timestamp from Firebase BigQuery Export?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

I am trying to extract near real-time analytics data from Firebase Analytics. The data is exported to BigQuery in real-time to `intraday table`. In order to sync real-time data to my database. I need to know when the record has logged to the table to avoid reading same records multiple times.

However, According to the Firebase document below, `event_timestamp` field is the timestamp when it is logged in a client device. `event_server_timestamp_offset` field is the offset between the collection time and upload time.

> https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en

So, I assumed the server logged time can be found by `event_timetamp + event_server_timestamp_offset`.
But I've found that `event_server_timestamp_offset` have both negative and positive number.

Does anyone know what the `event_server_timestamp_offset` is for? Unloading data before Collecting data is impossible.

Comment: One thing that might be affecting you, it's some timezone difference or time setting from the devices uploading, that might be causing this negative values - since negative should not be occurring. In case this is not your case, I would recommend you to reach out directly to the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support), so they can check it and verify the cause for this.

Comment: I think, the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62671147/432914.