# Data disappears when moving from events_intraday_ to events_

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am using BigQuery to analyze FirebaseAnalytics events. I use events_intraday_ for real-time analysis and events_ for daily analysis, and the data is automatically transferred from events_intraday to events_ after a certain time, but some data will disappear at that time. The table exists, but the data is clearly reduced. About 2 days out of a week's data is lost here. Please tell me why this happens.

Thanks.

Data should not be lost when moved from events_intraday_ to events_.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem that is easy problem fix is with the set up of intraday collects the data from “today” in realtime, you first need to agree with Google BigQuery on what “today” refers to. BigQuery can’t guess what timezone you want to query, which is why the default UNIX timestamp format of the event_timestamp column in BigQuery is always in UTC time. this post explains it clearly [Firebase BigQuery server offset time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238994/firebase-bigquery-server-offset-time/62671147#62671147)

Also I am not sure your last statement is correct "events_intraday_" and "events_" are not quite the same thing, an "events_intraday_" table contains raw, unsampled event data for the current day while the "events_" table contains processed and aggregated event data.

This processing of data after its collected but before data is exported to BigQuery, this means you would expect some data to be lost. Generally, the affected fields are traffic sources and linked marketing products (AdWords, Campaign Manager, etc.), if these are areas you are looking at its probably a GA4 processing issue.